# Extract Chemical Data from DBpedia via SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'd like to know how to submit a SPARQL query to DDBpedia and be given back a table that includes the information found in the Wikipedia "chembox" info box template, such as molecular weight or formula.

So, the first  step was just to make a query whose results should be a list of chemical substances that had the formula and molecularWeight properties included. But the following returns no results:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?y rdf:type dbpedia-owl:ChemicalSubstance.
  ?y rdfs:label ?Name .
  ?y dbpedia:molecularWeight ?molecularWeight .
  ?y dbpedia:formula ?formula .
  OPTIONAL {?y dbpedia-owl:iupacName ?iupacname} .
  FILTER (langMatches(lang(?Name),"en"))
}
LIMIT 50
```

[SPARQL Explorer at dbpedia.org](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20*%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fy%20rdf%3Atype%20dbpedia-owl%3AChemicalSubstance.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fy%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FName%20.%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fy%20dbpedia2%3Aformula%20%3Fformula%20%7D.%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fy%20dbpedia2%3AmolecularWeight%20%3FmolecularWeight%7D.%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fy%20dbpedia-owl%3AiupacName%20%3Fiupacname%7D%20.%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28langMatches%28lang%28%3FName%29%2C%22en%22%29%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%2050%0D%0A)

And so I'm stuck. Is something wrong with this query or does DBPedia really not collect that information from the Wikipedia chemboxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You caught the wrong namespace for both `dbpedia:molecularWeight` and `dbpedia:formula`. The correct namespace here would be `dbpedia2`.

Furthermore, there seem rarely any entries having a `dbpedia-owl:iupacName`, `dbpedia2:molecularWeight` *and*  `dbpedia2:formula`.

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?y rdf:type dbpedia-owl:ChemicalSubstance.
  ?y rdfs:label ?Name .
  OPTIONAL {?y dbpedia2:formula ?formula }.
  OPTIONAL {?y dbpedia2:molecularWeight ?molecularWeight}.
  OPTIONAL {?y dbpedia-owl:iupacName ?iupacname} .
  FILTER (langMatches(lang(?Name),"en"))
}
LIMIT 50
```

[SPARQL Explorer @dbpedia.org](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20*%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fy%20rdf%3Atype%20dbpedia-owl%3AChemicalSubstance.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fy%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FName%20.%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fy%20dbpedia2%3Aformula%20%3Fformula%20%7D.%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fy%20dbpedia2%3AmolecularWeight%20%3FmolecularWeight%7D.%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fy%20dbpedia-owl%3AiupacName%20%3Fiupacname%7D%20.%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28langMatches%28lang%28%3FName%29%2C%22en%22%29%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%2050%0D%0A)

---

To get the correct namespaces, you could either look at one example like [this](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?describe=http%3A//dbpedia.org/resource/Almandine) or get a list of all used properties for type `dbpedia-owl:ChemicalSubstance` using

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?rel WHERE {
  ?y rdf:type dbpedia-owl:ChemicalSubstance.
  ?y ?rel ?x
}
```

[SPARQL Explorer @dbpedia.org](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Frel%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fy%20rdf%3Atype%20dbpedia-owl%3AChemicalSubstance.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fy%20%3Frel%20%3Fx%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Thanks. Ugh. The formula field data is horribly messy and molecularWeight appears to be nonexistent.

Comment: @GlennHowes The `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/...` (dbpedia-owl:) properties have much cleaner data, and should be preferred over the dbprop: when they're available.

Comment: So you are saying there is an alternative to http://dbpedia.org/property/formula when I want to search by formula or retrieve a formula?