# dbpedia chemical element query

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I've been trying to make a DBpedia query to obtain data in the infobox related to chemical elements (not compounds/substances). I'm aiming for something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950938/extract-chemical-data-from-dbpedia-via-sparql) but for elements (like [this](https://blogs.ch.cam.ac.uk/pmr/2007/05/19/dbpedia-rdf-and-sparql-for-chemistry/)).

However, when I do a query like the following:

```
SELECT * WHERE{
 :Arsenic ?predicate ?object.
}
```

Most of the properties displayed in the examples don't even show up. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Assuming you use the prefix for DBpedia resources, your query is fine. And it brings all that is currently available in DBpedia - http://dbpedia.org/page/Arsenic. (Additionally you can get linked resources where `:Arsenic` is the object: `?subject ?predicate2 :Arsenic`. ) But it is indeed strange that it's less than what's in the infobox. I wonder if that could be an issue with the way the last BDpedia dataset was created.

Comment: yeah it appears there might just be a problem with the dataset. I wasn't able to extract the infobox for the page using the MediaWiki api either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you look at [the source of the Arsenic page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Arsenic&action=edit&section=0), it does not directly contain any of the data, instead, it has just: `{{Infobox arsenic}}`.

I think DBpedia is not able to extract the data from there, which is why you don't see anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

The  [Extract Chemical Data from DBpedia via SPARQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950938/extract-chemical-data-from-dbpedia-via-sparql) SO question wasn't so good about letting you know what the fully qualified URIs were in the query.  But if you look at the blog closely, the full URI of Arsenic is listed as `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Arsenic`.  That full URI is what you need.  You can use that by itself:

```
SELECT * 
WHERE {
   <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Arsenic> ?predicate ?object.
}
```

...or define a prefix for the DBPedia resource namespace:

```
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT * 
WHERE {
   dbpedia:Category:Arsenic ?predicate ?object.
}
```

note in this case that the `PREFIX` definition replaces `dbpedia:` with the namespace `http://dbpedia.org/resource/`.

Comment: http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Arsenic is wrong, it really should be http://dbpedia.org/resource/Arsenic.

Comment: Depends on what you want.  Both are valid URIs in DBPedia.